# Specifying Tf.exe and MsBuild version in CC.Net

Tags: tfs, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

**The problem**

I am porting a build to a newer version of CC.Net (from 1.4.4 to a very recent version of 1.6).  Previously the build mixed `<msbuild />` tags with `<exec />` tags that call batch files with `tf.exe` commands in them.

The build must have relied on the source control version being the same between the `msbuild` and `tf.exe` commands, because now I get an error on the `tf.exe` command:

> Unable to determine the workspace.

When I launch a command prompt, with runas as the same user the service is using, and call the same command the batch file used (from the same directory), I get the same error.

However if I launch a *Visual Studio 2010* command prompt, with runas, and call that command (from the same directory), I don't get the error.

This also makes sense, because the `%UserProfile%\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Team Foundation\3.0\Cache\VersionControl.config` file has the workspace mapping, but the `...\1.0\Cache\VersionControl.config` file does not.

**The solution I'd like to try**

I can't simply change the `PATH` for the batch file because it actually needs to build against an older version of Visual Studio, due to licensing.

I think I could solve this by specifying the TFS/msbuild version used with the `<msbuild />` tag.  But I'm not sure how to go about this.  I think it would be some sort of server configuration, but I haven't found anything about this in the docs.

My question is: How do I specify the version of TFS that Cruise Control uses for `<msbuild />` tags?  Or is there another way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to specify this directly with msbuild. The way it is solved at our place is that we set the executable for msbuild to a bat-file that's basically a copy of the desired `vcvars`-script (used by Visual Studio Command Prompt to set up the environment).

```
<tasks>
      <msbuild>
        <executable>vcvars_VC10_amd64.bat</executable>
        <workingDirectory>SomeFolder</workingDirectory>
        <environment>
            <variable name="foo" value="bar" />
        </environment>
        <projectFile>msbuild.proj</projectFile>
        <buildArgs>/m:2  /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64 /v:normal</buildArgs>
        <targets>Clean;Build;Test</targets>
        <timeout>3600</timeout>
      </msbuild>
  </tasks>
```

Maybe you could get away with setting up your desired paths using the `<environment>` property as well.

Comment: The `vcvars` solution sounds promising.  It would work for either task type.  Do you have a convenient way to get the path to the existing file, or do you just copy the file to the working folder through a manual process?

Comment: Found out I can find the vcvars batch file with: `"$(Vs80ComnTools)\..\..\VC\vcvarsall.bat"`.  The `executable` element is also very helpful, and can be used in the `sourcecontrol` element.

Answer (score 0):

I won't accept this solution, in case people have other solutions (or can solve the problem I directly asked about), but here's how I ended up solving my problem:

I added a workspace sync task to the top of the build tasks:

```
<tasks>
    <exec>
        <description>Sync the workspaces with the TFS server, for the version of TFS used in exec commands</description>
        <executable>Tf.exe</executable>
        <buildArgs>workspaces /s:$(TfsServer)</buildArgs>
    </exec>
```

This works because in my scenario, I don't care about the versioning as much as I do about the workspaces getting out of sync.